# How to force applications using a library to include specific application manifest settings on windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, window

I have a visual studio solution that consists of two different projects:

- A game engine library
- The game executable that references the game engine library

The game engine handles window resolution changes and so I want to make it so that any application built with it is DPI aware.
To do that I could use SetDpiAwareness in the game engine's source code, but Microsoft recommends using an application manifest file instead.

I found that I can add an application manifest file to the game executable project, but because the engine is used for multiple projects, I would like the game engine library to have the application manifest and embed it into any game executable project that uses it.

This will prevent the user having to set up a manifest for every new project and potentially forgetting to enable dpi awareness. Also, because the engine handles all resolution code, it should be its responsibility to declare whether it is dpi aware or not.

Is there any way to set it up so that any executable project using the game engine library gets an application manifest embedded in it?

Comment: We recommended that you embed the manifest of your application or library inside the final binary because this guarantees correct runtime behavior in most scenarios. For more details, I suggest you could refer to the Docs: [How to: Embed a Manifest Inside a C/C++ Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-embed-a-manifest-inside-a-c-cpp-application?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the manifest-related properties in the exported [property pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/property-pages-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160) of your game engine project. So when you reference game engine project in other projects these properties will be pulled along.